# HTML autowrap autocenter charaters in pre tags

Tags: html, css

I wanted to put a box to accent some queries, just on the one page - not the whole website. So I put in an inline style to prototype the change.  I had to trim the characters inside of the pre tags to fit within the border box. 
Is there a way where I could autowrap and autocenter the characters in the div class box, without manually trimming the characters in the pre tags ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- header, sitebranding, tagline, and bodycontent -->

<head>
  <title> Casper Support  </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="wiki.css" />
  <style>
    .box {
      height: 70px ;
      width:  1000px ;
      position: relative  ;
      border: 2px solid #287EC7 ;
      background: #F5F5F5 ;
     }
  </style>
</head>
 <body>
 <h3 id="overdue_meeting"> The overdue Jira Query </h3>
 <p> query </p>
 <div class="box">
 <pre> <code> 
  project = Casper AND status != Closed AND (component = "Queue - Support" OR assignee in (casper1, casper2, casper3, casper4, casper5, casper6, casper7, casper8)) AND (duedate < 7d OR duedate < endOfDay() OR duedate is EMPTY) ORDER BY id ASC 
 </code> </pre>
 </div>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flexbox for vertical centering

```
.box {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Turn off the `white-space:pre` and use `text-align:center` for the wrap and horizontal  centering.

```
.box pre {
  white-space:normal; /* or white-space:pre-wrap to not collapse spaces */
  text-align:center;
}
```

```css
.box {
    height: 70px ;
    width:  1000px ;
    position: relative  ;
    border: 2px solid #287EC7 ;
    background: #F5F5F5 ;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
   }
.box pre {
  white-space:normal;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <h3 id="overdue_meeting"> The overdue Jira Query </h3>
 <p> query </p>
 <div class="box">
 <pre> <code> 
  project = Casper AND status != Closed AND (component = "Queue - Support" OR assignee in (casper1, casper2, casper3, casper4,                      casper5, casper6, casper7, casper8)) AND (duedate < 7d OR duedate < endOfDay() OR duedate is EMPTY) ORDER BY id ASC 
 </code> </pre>
 </div>
```